# Java Spring Data JPA and REST API: exclude fields of nested JSON object

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-json

Currently I'm using Spring Data JPA 2.2.1 with a Spring Boot Web 2.2.1 for a REST API service.

A getter call to **/categories** returns the following JSON, which in fact is the desired result:

```
[
    {
        "category1": "A",
        "category2": "B",
        "subcategories": []
    },
    {
        "category1": "A",
        "category2": "B",
        "subcategories": [{
                "field1": "A",
                "field2": "B",
                "field3": "C",
                "field4": "D"
        }]
    },
.........
.........
]
```

**Entities:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
@Getter @Setter
public class Category {

    @JsonIgnore
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String category1;
    private String category2;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Subcategory> subcategories;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "subcategory")
@Getter @Setter
public class Subcategory {

    @JsonIgnore
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @JsonIgnore
    private int parent;
    private String field1;
    private String field2;
    private String field3;
    private String field4;
}
```

**Controller:**

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

    private final DataService dataService;

    @Autowired
    public MyController(DataService dataService) {
        this.dataService = dataService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/categories")
    public List<Category> getAllCategories() {
        return dataService.getAllCategories();
    }
```

**Repository**

```
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<Category, Long> {
    List<MyRepository> findAll();
}
```

**DataService**

```
@Component
public class DataService {
    private MyRepository myRepository;

    @Autowired
    public DataService(MyRepository myRepository) {
        this.myRepository = myRepository;
    }

    public List<Category> getAllCategories() { return myRepository.findAll(); }
```

I now want to add a new call to my API, **/limitedCategories**, which does not return all of the fields. For example, "category2" of the parent entity, and "field4" of the nested entity shall be excluded.

**Problem:**

- I don't manage to manually select the desired fields within my JPA Repository, and also wouldn't know how to deal with the nested object.
- The simple idea to just use findAll and exclude those fields using @JsonIgnore is not possible, as my first request still needs those fields.
- When using @Query annotation within my repository to fetch only the desired fields, I cannot find a way to fetch the nested fields for my JSON.

Thanks in advance.

I'm using Spring Data JPA 2.2.1 with a Spring Boot Web 2.2.1.

Comment: Entities represent what you want to persist in your database tables. Use a different (DTO) class to represent what you want to return as JSON from your endpoint. Transform your entities into instances of this DTO class.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jackson API, I recommend you to use @JsonView feature.

For example

```
class Person {
   // it will be add always
   Integer id;

   // it will be add only for PutFirstName case
   @JsonView(Views.PutFirstName.class)
   String firstName;

   // it will be add only for PutLastName case
   @JsonView(Views.PutLastName.class)
   String lastName;
} 

class Views {
   static class PutFirstName{}
   static class PutLastNastName{}
}

// Controller 
@JsonView(Views.PutFirstName.class)
@GetMapping
Person getFirstName(){
     // result : {id,firstName}
}

@JsonView(Views.PutLastName.class)
@GetMapping
Person getLastName(){
    // result : {id, lastName}
}
```